# Calling LocalReport.Render in background thread

Tags: .net, multithreading, reporting-services, reportviewer

I have been working with the Winforms ReportViewer control for a while now.  I have added a custom toolbar, and am handling all report functions manually.

My problem is with extra large reports.  In order to render my reports to Image (which I use to print) I call the ReportViewer.LocalReport.Render method.  Larger reports end up freezing the UI for quite a while.

My plan is to "pre-fetch" the rendered images when a report is requested.  I am trying to do this in a background thread.  Everything I have tried, results in the UI being unresponsive during the Render call.

Is there something about the Render call that would cause a Thread (that has nothing to do with the UI thread) to somehow lock the UI thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible.

The Render method will never allow to be run as a thread.